# Whats that sound my amp makes?

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers, sound

i have an electric guitar (Fender Stratocaster classic series 50's mexican) and a Fender Champion 40 amp. Everytime i put my amp on and turn up the volume it makes a really buzzy sound. I figuered out that this happens when im close to my laptop witch i usually play! Any good solutions except from change my laptop ( also it hasnt got any battery if that makes any sense, its always plugged in)! Thank you!!

Comment: im sorry! the sound comes from the amp.

Comment: Does the sound change significantly when you choose different pickup combinations with the 5-way switch, or does it stay mostly the same?

Comment: it changes a bit. the buzzy sound is louder on the neck pickup but its also loud on the other 4

Comment: yeah thats what happens!!! Thank you!! im about to check it!!! :)

Comment: @ToddWilcox  : This question is not really a dup, because there is a computer involved, which, based on the question, may be the source of the problem. If so, grounding will not help and you'd need some awfully good shielding to keep out noise from a poorly executed switching power supply, the bane of many an audiophile or radio enthusiast.

Answer (score 1):

> ( also it hasnt got any battery if that makes any sense, its always
>   plugged in)

Your laptop generates some electronic noise that could get pulled in by a nearby audio device, but that would usually be only at close range - a foot or two.

Your #1 suspect is **the power supply of your laptop** - such power supplies can be **very noisy** over a considerable distance, if they aren't well designed to squelch electronic noise.

If possible, put your laptop on batteries and see if that helps.

Comment: @chris - first let's see if I'm right. :)